# How to set Google+ photos to be Public-Unlisted (as you could do with PicasaWeb)?

Tags: privacy, google-plus-photos

Previously, if I uploaded photos from Picasa to PicasaWeb, I could specify them as Public but Unlisted. So you had to have the link to view them but no login was required.

I don't see that option now that Picasa uploads to Google+.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see a **Visible to:** title when you click through to the photo album you want to share via a private link.

Click that and you should see an overlay appear which includes an option to:

> Share via link

Copy and paste and send that link to whomever you want to have access to the album, while still keeping it away from public listing.

> [image: photo album sharing options]

You can also click on the Options menu and **Share album via link**.

If you wanted to pass around an individual photo, just right-click and open the image itself into a new tab for its URL or "Copy the image URL" (or your browser equivalent to grabbing the URL of an image from the page).